# Airflow DAG Loop - How to make each iteration sequential instead of parallel

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an Apache Airflow DAG like so:

```
DAG_NAME='my_dag'
sections = ["0", "1", "2", "3"]

with DAG(DAG_NAME, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None) as dag:

        for s in sections:
            a = DummyOperator(task_id=f"section_{s}_start")
            b = SubDagOperator(task_id=f"init_{s}_subdag",subdag=init_section(DAG_NAME,f"init_{s}_subdag", default_args))
            c = SubDagOperator(task_id=f"process_{s}_subdag", subdag=process_section(DAG_NAME,f"process_{s}_subdag", default_args))
            d = SubDagOperator(task_id=f"update_{s}_subdag", subdag=update_section(DAG_NAME,f"update_{s}_subdag", default_args))
            e = DummyOperator(task_id=f"section_{s}_end")
            a>>b>>c>>d>>e
```

This code renders my tasks like so[image]

[image]

How can I make the sequence of tasks be:

section_0_start>>init_0_subdag>>process_0_subdag>>update_0_subdag>>section_0_end
section_0_end>>section_1_start
section_1_start>>init_1_subdag>>process_1_subdag>>update_1_subdag>>section_1_end

.....

and so on in sequence from section 0 ending with section 3 tasks

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need subDAGs for this ?

Comment: @MeghdeepRay each subdag has more tasks within it which need to be run in parallel. For instance Im reading 5 files in each processing subdag which need to be run in parallel. Also I would like my team to reuse my subdags for their code so im trying to make a generic template.

Do you have any other better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the for-loop like this:

```
    previous_e = None
    for s in sections:
        a = ...
        ...
        e = ...
        if previous_e:
            previous_e >> a
        a>>b>>c>>d>>e
        previous_e = e
```