# Airflow tasks iterating over list should run sequentially

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running a tasks based on a list. The task id gets incremented based on the list. After the completion of these tasks I want another tasks to execute . Following is the code:

```
with DAG('test',) as dag:

        t1 = [PythonOperator(
        task_id=f"task_hour_{hours}",
        python_callable=hourly_job,
        op_kwargs={
        "hour": hours
        }
        ) for hours in ['01', '02', '03']
        ]
    
        t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="daily",
        python_callable=daily_job
        )
    t1 >> t2
```

What is happening is these `hourly` tasks are all running in parallel followed up by `daily` task for each one of them. Like this:

```
task_hour_01 >> daily
task_hour_02 >> daily
task_hour_03 >> daily
```

What i want to happen is that these `hourly` tasks should execute sequentially and lastly the `daily` task should execute:

```
task_hour_01 >> task_hour_02 >> task_hour_03 >> daily
```

So there are two problems:

- The tasks should run in sequence.
- The daily task should be the last task to execute and should run only
  once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is in the right direction you are just missing setting the dependencies with`chain`:

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

# Replace with your function logic
def hourly_job():
    return 'hourly'


# Replace with your function logic
def daily_job():
    return 'daily'


with DAG(dag_id='test', start_date=datetime(2022, 2, 16)) as dag:
    hours = ['01', '02', '03']
    op_list = [
        PythonOperator(task_id=f"task_hour_{hour}", python_callable=hourly_job, op_kwargs={"hour": hour})
        for hour in hours]
    chain(*op_list)
    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="daily",
        python_callable=daily_job
    )

    op_list[-1] >> t2
```

[image]

Comment: available from airflow 2. not in airflow 1.

Comment: It will work also in Airflow 1 - all you need is just changing the imports

Comment: Would be worth a little comment nothing that the [-1] means chain the LAST operation in the op list with t2.  I know, but it tripped me up for a moment with so many other aspects to consider. Polyglot pain.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56292433/airflow-dag-loop-how-to-make-each-iteration-sequential-instead-of-parallel), you could use and auxiliar variable like `t0` to initialize and handle your Operators.

```
with DAG('test',) as dag:
    hours = ['01', '02', '03']
    t0 = None

    for hour in hours:
        t1 = PythonOperator(
             task_id=f"task_hour_{hours}",
             python_callable=hourly_job,
             op_kwargs={"hour": hour}
        if t0 is not None:
            t0 >> t1
        t0 = t1
    t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="daily",
    python_callable=daily_job
    )
t1 >> t2
```

Comment: better way for Airflow 1.